# My application generates an XML which is not human-readable

Tags: python, xml

I am creating a simple GUI application to manage unknown words while learning a new language. The words are loaded/saved from/into the XML document, but here is how it looks:

```
<Words><Word><Word>test1</Word><Explanation>test1</Explanation><Translation>test1</Translation><Examples>test1</Examples></Word><Word><Word>test2</Word><Explanation>test2</Explanation><Translation>test2</Translation><Examples>test2</Examples></Word><Word><Word>test3</Word><Explanation>test3</Explanation><Translation>test3</Translation><Examples>test3</Examples></Word><Word><Word>test4</Word><Explanation>test4</Explanation><Translation>test4</Translation><Examples>test4</Examples></Word><Word><Word>test5</Word><Explanation>test5</Explanation><Translation>test5</Translation><Examples>test5</Examples></Word></Words>
```

Everything is in one line, and it should be like this:

```
<Words>
   <Word>
      <Word>test</Word>
      <Explanation>test</Explanation>
      <Translation>test</Translation>
      <Examples>test</Examples>
   </Word>
</Words>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
# Vocabulary.py
# GUI program to manage unknown words

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os


class Word:

    def __init__(self, wordorphrase, explanation, translation, example):
        self.wordorphrase = wordorphrase
        self.explanation = explanation
        self.example = example
        self.translation = translation

class Vocabulary(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.master.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.master.title("Vocabulary")
        self.create_widgets()
        self.words = []
        self.load_words()

    def on_closing(self):

        self.save_all()

        if messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you want to quit?"):
            self.master.destroy()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.buttons_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.buttons_frame.grid(row = 10, sticky = W)

        self.search_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.search_frame.grid(row = 1, sticky = W, columnspan = 2)

        self.comboBox = ttk.Combobox(self.search_frame,
                                     width = 3)
        self.comboBox.grid(row = 0, column = 14, sticky = W)
        self.comboBox['values'] = ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' )

        self.btn_Add = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                              text = 'Add',
                              command = self.add_item)
        self.btn_Add.grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Remove = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                 text = 'Remove',
                                 command = self.remove_item)

        self.btn_Remove.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Edit = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Edit',
                               command = self.edit_item)
        self.btn_Edit.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Save = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                               text = 'Save',
                               command = self.save_item)
        self.btn_Save.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W)

        self.btn_Refresh = Button(self.buttons_frame,
                                  text = 'Refresh',
                                  command = self.refresh_all)
        self.btn_Refresh.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky = W)

        self.lblSearch = Label(self.search_frame, text = 'SEARCH: ')
        self.lblSearch.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Search = Text(self.search_frame,
                               height = 1,
                               width = 70)
        self.txt_Search.grid(row = 0, column = 6, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

        self.lblWordsOrPhrases = Label(self.master, text = 'WORDS/PHRASES:')
        self.lblWordsOrPhrases.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.lblWordOrPhrase = Label(self.master, text = 'Word or phrase:')
        self.lblWordOrPhrase.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.listBox = Listbox(self.master,
                               selectmode='multiple',
                               height = 34,
                               width = 38)
        self.listBox.grid(row = 3, column = 0, rowspan = 7, sticky = W)

        self.txt_WordOrPhrase = Text(self.master,
                                     height = 1,
                                     width = 40)
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExplanation = Label(self.master, text = 'Explanation:')
        self.lblExplanation.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Explanation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Explanation.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblTranslation = Label(self.master, text = 'Translation:')
        self.lblTranslation.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Translation = Text(self.master,
                                    height = 10,
                                    width = 40)
        self.txt_Translation.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = N)

        self.lblExamples = Label(self.master, text = 'Example(s):')
        self.lblExamples.grid(row = 8, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_Example = Text(self.master,
                                height = 10,
                                width = 40)
        self.txt_Example.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = S)

    def load_words(self):

        self.listBox.delete(0, END)
        self.words.clear()

        path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
        vocabulary = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')

        if not os.path.exists(vocabulary):
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(vocabulary)):
                os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(vocabulary))
            doc = ET.Element('Words')
            tree = ET.ElementTree(doc)
            tree.write(vocabulary)
        else:
            tree = ET.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)

        for node in tree.findall('Word'):
            w = Word(node.find('Word').text, node.find('Explanation').text, node.find('Translation').text,
                     node.find('Examples').text)

            self.words.append(w)
            self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)

    def save_all(self):

        path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
        vocabulary = os.path.join(path, 'Vocabulary', 'Words.xml')

        tree = ET.ElementTree(file=vocabulary)

        for xNode in tree.getroot().findall('Word'):
            tree.getroot().remove(xNode)

        for w in self.words:
            xTop = ET.Element('Word')
            xWord = ET.Element('Word')
            xExplanation = ET.Element('Explanation')
            xTranslation = ET.Element('Translation')
            xExamples = ET.Element('Examples')

            xWord.text = w.wordorphrase
            xExplanation.text = w.explanation
            xTranslation.text = w.translation
            xExamples.text = w.example

            xTop.append(xWord)
            xTop.append(xExplanation)
            xTop.append(xTranslation)
            xTop.append(xExamples)

            tree.getroot().append(xTop)

        tree.write(vocabulary)

    def add_item(self):

        w = Word(self.get_word(), self.get_explanation(), self.get_translation(), self.get_example())

        self.words.append(w)

        self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)

        self.clear_all()

        self.save_all()

    def remove_item(self):
        word = self.listBox.get(ACTIVE)
        new_word_list = []  # initialize empty list
        delete_idxs = []
        for idx, item in enumerate(self.words):
            if item.wordorphrase == word:
                delete_idxs.append(idx)
            else:
                new_word_list.append(item)
        self.words = new_word_list  # overwrite the old word_list with the new one
        for idx in reversed(delete_idxs):
            self.listBox.delete(idx)

    def edit_item(self):
        pass

    def save_item(self):
        pass

    def clear_all(self):
        self.txt_WordOrPhrase.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Explanation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Translation.delete('1.0', END)
        self.txt_Example.delete('1.0', END)

    def refresh_all(self):
        pass

    def get_word(self):
        return self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_explanation(self):
        return self.txt_Explanation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_translation(self):
        return self.txt_Translation.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def get_example(self):
        return self.txt_Example.get('1.0', '1.0 lineend')

    def find_word(word):
        for x in self.words:
            if x.wordorphrase == word:
                return x


def main():
    root = Tk()
    gui = Vocabulary(root)
    root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', gui.on_closing)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It seems odd to have a `<Word>` inside a `<Word>`. You have a single tag `<Word>` that means two different things.  Is that intentional? This is unrelated to the problem you are experiencing, but it will make the data easier to parse if your tags were unique (eg: `<Wordlist><Worddata><Word>...`)

Comment: Yeah, I have to admit it does. I'll have to think of something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use just ET.Element. Try to use ET.SubElement.

Useful link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement

For example on your code:

```
 xTop = ET.Element('Word')
 xWord = ET.Element('Word')
 xExplanation = ET.Element('Explanation')
 xTranslation = ET.Element('Translation')
 xExamples = ET.Element('Examples')
```

I try to change in:

```
Words field: words = ET.Element('Words')

 xTop = ET.SubElement(words,'Word')
 xWord = ET.SubElement(xTop,'Word')
 xExplanation = ET.SubElement(xTop,'Explanation')
 xTranslation = ET.SubElement(xTop,'Translation')
 xExamples = ET.SubElement(xTop,'Examples')
```

Another useful link: https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html#pretty-printing-xml

Comment: Could you show the implementation on my code please?

Comment: I added example in answer post. Good luck!

*I use this reference for changes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents

Comment: Nothing changes, and what is `Words field: words = ET.Element('Words')`?

Comment: words = ET.Element('Words') is <Words> ... </Words> the place where you put the rest of informations.

Comment: I'm sorry man, nothing changes. It's still everything in one line. Have you tested your code?

Comment: Try that print: https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html#pretty-printing-xml